# Unfortunately, Listview has stopped working (android error)

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm experiencing the problem "Unfortunately, your listview has stopped working" when i was using the android emulator to run my codes. 
Please take a look at my codes thanks!

For activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.it3783.listview.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose a location..."/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:id="@+id/spLocations"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/superHerosTV"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

For MainActivity.java:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter;
    TextView tvSelection;
    ListView lvLocation;

    String []strArray;
    String []superHeros = {"1. Batman\n 2. SpiderMan", "1. Peter Pan\n2. Superman",
            "1. IronMan\n2. Peter Pan", "1. SnowWhite \n2. Gingerbreadman"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);

        tvSelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superHerosTV);
        lvLocation = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spLocations);

        Resources myRes = this.getResources();
        strArray = myRes.getStringArray(R.array.locationArea);

        lvLocation.setAdapter(adapter);

        lvLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String text = strArray[position];
                tvSelection.setText(text);
            }
        });

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locationArea, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    }
}
```

For strings.xml:

```
    <resources>
    <string name="app_name">ListView</string>

    <string-array name="locationArea">

        <item>North</item>
        <item>South</item>
        <item>East</item>
        <item>West</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: put your stacktrace here

Comment: [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strArray);
```

This line in your onCreate methods takes the strArray, which is not initialized so its value is null.
Now when you set the adapter with null data to the listview, it crashes.